# ClassNotFound Exception in Lein (can't compile)

Tags: clojure

I am trying to :gen-class a Servlet
This is my code:

```
(ns test.test 
(:import (java.io PrintWriter) (javax.servlet.http HttpServlet))
(:gen-class :name test.TestServlet :extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet))

(defn -doGet[request response]
    (let [wrtr (.getWriter response)]
        (.println wrtr "hello from clojure")))
```

it can't be compiled by Lein
it said **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet (Test.clj:1)**

I already modified the :library-path in Lein as ":library-path "/home/long/workspaces/spring/LongHDi/war/WEB-INF/lib" but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea why?

I am trying to work with Google App Engine. The servlet class I want to extend is already in the lib folder I specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of lein are you using ?

I downloaded jetty from [here](http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-8.1.7/), and lein [version1](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/1.x/sample.project.clj) worked for me with project.clj

```
(defproject st2 "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
 :description "FIXME: write description"
 :library-path "/Users/Niko/Downloads/jetty-hightide-8.1.7.v20120910/lib"
 :aot [st2.core]
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]])
```

with st2.core the same as your code:

```
(ns st2.core
 (:import (java.io PrintWriter) (javax.servlet.http HttpServlet))
 (:gen-class :name test.TestServlet :extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet))

(defn -doGet[request response]
  (let [wrtr (.getWriter response)]
    (.println wrtr "hello from clojure")))
```

If you are using lein2, :library-path is not supported so I suspect you would have to add the dependencies "a-la-maven" and add them to your project dependencies.

Comment: That's weird. I am using Lein version 1

Comment: Oh, it works now. The jar file which I specified is not in the lib folder of the workspace as I thought. It lies in a folder of Springsource Tool Suite plug-in. Thank you for your confirmation that it works for you.

Comment: the servlet.jar file would not be in the war itself ?

Comment: it is in a directory which is in a folder for plugins of Spring Source Toolsuite